# update embedded excel pivot in powerpoint using VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpoint, refresh

I have some pivot tables in powerpoint that I embedded. I chose to embed rather than just regular linking as I need to update the pivot tables daily and need to shape them to give only the relevant information.(Sometimes there is more data than the day before which cannot be seen when linking normally as the"window" is fixed.)

I am still very new to the VBA coding field and require a code that will open my Microsoft excel worksheet opject then refresh the pivot inside the object and close it again. I have written code to open the document, save and close the document which is working correctly. I only require that little refresh bit.

Many thanks in advance